# Python Script to load JSON file and save values to variables

Tags: python, json

Hello I have this code to load a JSON file and I want to pass values to variables:

```
with open('C:/files/response.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for item in data:   
    if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values.append(item['ITEM']['TOTALQTY'])

testvalue = str(property_values[0])
print (testvalue)
```

But for that instance only I have the error:

```
“TypeError: string indices must be integers”
```

Also I want to call in the same way the values:

DESCRIPTION, PARTNUM, UNITPRICE, ITEMNO, VENDORDESCR

I pretend to use the same way:

```
  if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values2.append(item['ITEM']['DESCRIPTION'])

    if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values3.append(item['ITEM']['PARTNUM'])

    if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values4.append(item['ITEM']['UNITPRICE'])

    if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values5.append(item['ITEM']['ITEMNO'])

    if 'XMLRESPONSE' in item:
        property_values6.append(item['ITEM']['VENDORDESCR'])
```

But is obvious is not working. How can I modify the script to make it read that values?

This is the JSON file:

```
{
   "XMLRESPONSE": {
      "ITEM": {
         "PARTNUM": "876666",
         "UNITPRICE": "$1.50",
         "ITEMNO": "55667",
         "VENDORITEMNO": "1206613",
         "DESCRIPTION": "tests",
         "VENDORDESCR": "test",
         "ERP": "$1,999.00",
         "REBATEVALUE": "$0.00",
         "REBATEENDDATE": null,
         "ISNONSTOCK": "false",
         "ISFACTORYDIRECT": "false",
         "FREEFRT": "true",
         "RESTRICTED": "false",
         "BRANCHQTY": [
            {
               "BRANCH": "test",
               "QTY": "0",
               "INSTOCKDATE": null
            },
            {
               "BRANCH": "test",
               "QTY": "2",
               "INSTOCKDATE": null
            },
            {
               "BRANCH": "test",
               "QTY": "5",
               "INSTOCKDATE": null
            },
            {
               "BRANCH": "test",
               "QTY": "0",
               "INSTOCKDATE": null
            }
         ],
         "TOTALQTY": "7"
      },
      "STATUS": "success"
   }
}
```

I tried to use the lines of code above but I receive errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to string into index which is not  allowed in Python. When you load json you use dictionary:

```
property_values = []
property_values2 = []
property_values3 = []
property_values4 = []
property_values5 = []
property_values6 = []

if 'XMLRESPONSE' in data:
    item = data['XMLRESPONSE']['ITEM']
    property_values.append(item['TOTALQTY'])
    property_values2.append(item['DESCRIPTION'])
    property_values3.append(item['PARTNUM'])
    property_values4.append(item['UNITPRICE'])
    property_values5.append(item['ITEMNO'])
    property_values6.append(item['VENDORDESCR'])

testvalue = str(property_values[0])
print(testvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a dict, making `item` a string.

You cannot index a string by a string.

You don't need a for loop.

```
with open('C:/files/response.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

xml_response = data.get('XMLRESPONSE')
if xml_response:
    property_values2.append(xml_response['DESCRIPTION'])
    property_values3.append(xml_response['PARTNUM'])
    ...
```

I suggest you use a class to parse data into, not "parallel lists"